# How to prove/check a random generator is a unifrom random distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms

If I have access to a random integer generator that produces values in the range from $0$ to $N-1$, how can I verify whether this generator truly produces a uniform random distribution?

Simply analyzing the frequencies of generated numbers might not be sufficient, as the sequence could be cyclic, repeating in the order of $0, 1, \cdots, N-1$, and then starting over from $0$.

I believe that examining only $M$ samples ($M >> N$ is some fixed large number) for this purpose might be inadequate. Perhaps considering the time series of the generated numbers is crucial. Are there any advanced techniques available for accurately assessing this random number generator?

Comment: https://www.americanscientist.org/sites/americanscientist.org/files/20144141249210337-2014-05TechnologueFp170.jpg

Comment: Professor Melissa O'Neill's blog has several articles on the generation and testing of random integers: https://www.pcg-random.org/blog/

Comment: If you put "testing random number generators" into a search engine, you should find many references.  There is no definitive test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really long comment.
Yes, there are advanced techniques called statistical tests that can help us determine whether a random number generator produces a uniform random distribution..

One common statistical test is the Diehard battery of tests, which includes a st of 26 tests that cover various aspects of randomness. These tests include checks for uniformity, independence, and lack of patterns in the generated sequence.

Another test is the Monte Carlo test, which involves generating a large number of sequences using the same generator and comparing their properties to those of truly random sequences. If the generated sequences pass certain statistical tests with high confidence, then we can say that the generator is likely producing a uniform random distribution.

It's also important to note that while these tests can provide us with confidence in the randomness of a generator, they cannot prove that it is truly random. Randomness is inherently unpredictable.

To further improve the quality of our random number generator, you can use techniques like pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs), which are deterministic algorithms that produce sequences that appear to be random but are repeatable given the same initial state.

To sum up, while analyzing frequencies might not be sufficient for testing randomness, advanced statistical tests like the Diehard battery and Monte Carlo test can help you determine whether a random number generator produces a uniform random distribution. Additionally, using PRNGs with appropriate testing can improve the quality and reliability of your generated sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If the generator is a completely black box to you, then you technically can't, no matter how many numbers it has generated and what their distribution looks like, it might only generate zeroes for all future, which would invalidate any conclusion you've drawn based on the first set of numbers. (except that a sequence of zeroes can be the output of a RNG).

But in most cases that's just a technicality. Even black boxes rarely behaves like that. It is more likely that they (black boxes) behave as they are advertised to.
If you know anything about the algorithm (or trusts the black box) you can look at it to convince yourself that it is not (eventually) obviously flawed, then a set of tests e.g. like those @AdityaNaskar mentions is their answer is the way to go.